# How do I change the function of the earphone button?

Tags: music-player, customization, headphones

I have a Nexus S running Gingerbread and I use the stock app to listen to music. The bundled earphone has a button that plays/pauses music, but I find this redundant since I can either reduce the volume or pull out the earphone jack when I want to interact with the rest of the world.

It would be really awesome if I could change the function to "Next Track" instead since it'd be easy to skip a track while I'm on my bike. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you've tried double clicking it? On my phone (Dell Streak), a double-click skips to the next track. Might just be DoubleTwist that, though, I'm not sure.

Comment: Oh wow. That works perfectly on the Winamp App! THANK YOU! (Not sure how to make the stock app respond to the button instead of Winamp, though)

Comment: It works for the stock app too. But the double-click time threshold is really low. It's really hard to double-click fast enough. Is there a way to change the time?

Answer (score 2):

There's an app available in the market called [ButtonRemapper](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.beansoft.buttonremapper_sgs&feature=search_result), and the developer has a thread open on XDA that you can find [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=850464).  There is a version specifically designed for the Samasung Galaxy S (<s>which I think is what the Nexus S was based off?</s>  **See my edit below.**) so you might want to try that version first, but I think your best bet is going to be trying this app and seeing if it lets you do what you want.

Oh, this app requires root access.  All the standard disclaimers apply.

**Edit:** Based on [this link](http://www.themobileblog.in/2010/12/07/google-nexus-s-vs-samsung-galaxy-s/) they seem close but have important internal differences.  I'm not sure how that will affect whether or not that app made for the Galaxy S will work for you.

Comment: I believe this app allows you to edit what the phones buttons do, not the headphones buttons.

Comment: @Matt - Some of the information on the XDA thread led me to believe it might have expanded support for other buttons.  It's a free app so there isn't much harm in giving it a shot if he's already rooted, and I think finding a non-root solution for this is pretty unlikely anyway.

Comment: True, no harm in trying.  I'm not sure it would require root to do what he wants to do though.  I believe that any given app can decide how it handles the multimedia buttons on headphones.  The reason you need root access for buttonremapper is because it's changing the intended functionality to the phones hardware itself which is locked out for security reasons.

Comment: @Matt - I figured the security issue would extend beyond the physical phone itself.  Imagine if you built a Bluetooth device with some kind of malicious app embedded on it and you could remap some physical button on the Bluetooth device to reboot the phone into recovery mode or something.

Comment: That's a good point. hopefully this works. I'd really like this functionality myself.